# Accesing an array item for a class binding in a v-for loop

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When using Vue's dynamic class binding to use a ternary operator to bind a class based on the currentValue and the id of the items in my looped array, Vue seems to ignore the class completely.

Both the 'first' and 'last' class bindings work, but when using the item.id, the class is never assigned. However the function is fired because the event is successfully emitted and the currentValue var updated.

**ContentSwitcher.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="content-switcher-wrapper">
    <section class="content-items">
      <a v-for="(item, index) in options"
         class="content-item"
         :class="[ index === 0 ? 'first' : '',
                   index === options.length -1 ? 'last' : '',
                   item.id === currentValue ? 'selected' : '',]"
         @click="updateSelected(item.id)">
        {{ item.text }}
      </a>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class ContentSwitcher extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  public options!: any;

  public currentValue!: string;

  public created(): void {
    this.currentValue = this.options[0].id;
  }

  public updateSelected(value: string): void {
    this.currentValue = value;
    this.$emit('contentSwitcherUpdated', value);
  }
}
</script>
```

**Usage**

```
<content-switcher :options="tabSwitcherOptions"></content-switcher>
```

**Options passed**

```
  private tabSwitcherOptions: any = [
    {
      id: 'week',
      text: 'Week',
    },
    {
      id: 'month',
      text: 'Maand',
    },
  ];
```

When clicking on "Month", the event is emmited, however the classed 'selected' is never added to the tag.

Comment: I don't believe it's the cause of your problem but your array of classes can be simplified by using the object syntax instead: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your component is that your data property in the typescript class is `undefined` upon initialization. So `currentValue` is not reactive.

From the [official Vue documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#undefined-will-not-be-reactive)

> To take consistency between the decorator behavior of Babel and TypeScript, vue-class-component does not make a property reactive if it has undefined as initial value. You should use null as initial value or use data hook to initialize undefined property instead.

You need to initialize your data properties using a hook:

```
@Component
export default class ContentSwitcher extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  public options!: any;

  public currentValue!: string;

  // Here!
  data () {
    return {
      currentValue: undefined
    }
  }

  public created(): void {
    this.currentValue = this.options[0].id;
  }

  public updateSelected(value: string): void {
    this.currentValue = value;
    this.$emit('contentSwitcherUpdated', value);
  }
}
```

Here's the [working example on codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-srirs)

Also, your code works fine when I test it in Javascript.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('content-switcher', {
  template: `
<div class="content-switcher-wrapper">
  Selected: {{ currentValue }}
  </br>
  <section class="content-items">
    <a v-for="(item, index) in options"
       class="content-item"
       :class="[ index === 0 ? 'first' : '',
                 index === options.length -1 ? 'last' : '',
                 item.id === currentValue ? 'selected' : '',]"
       @click="updateSelected(item.id)">
      {{ item.text }}
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
  `,
  props: {
    options: Array
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentValue: undefined,
  }),
  created() {
    this.currentValue = this.options[0].id;
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelected(value) {
      this.currentValue = value;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   template: `
    <div>
     <content-switcher :options="tabSwitcherOptions" />
   </div>
   `,
   data: () => ({
      tabSwitcherOptions: [
        {
          id: 'week',
          text: 'Week',
        },
        {
          id: 'day',
          text: 'Day',
        },
        {
          id: 'month',
          text: 'Maand',
        },
      ]
   })
})
```

```css
.first { color: red; }
.last { color: green; }
.selected { font-size: 2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is actually a reactivity issue seen here `public currentValue!: string`. `currentValue` is not assigned until the created hook. The created hook is NOT a constructor and gets executed after the instantiation which means when the component is initially created `currentValue` is actually undefined. Instance properties must have an initial value for change detection to happen. Change it to `public currentValue: string = '';` and you should see the results you are looking for.

See [Declaring-Reactive-Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) for more info.